# Pagination and Filtering at the same time

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

views.py

```
class CourseListView(ListView):
    model = Course
    context_object_name = "courses"
    template_name = "academics/course_list.html"
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q') if self.request.GET.get('q') != None else ''
        return Course.objects.filter(major__major__icontains=q).order_by('course')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = "Our Courses"
        context['majors'] = Major.objects.all()
        return context
```

academics/course_list.html

```
...
      <div class="col-12">
        <!-- courses by major -->
        <ul class="list-inline text-center filter-controls mb-5">
          <li class="list-inline-item m-3 text-uppercase active">
            <a class="text-dark" href="{% url 'course-list' %}">All</a>
          </li>
          {% for major in majors %}
            <li class="list-inline-item m-3 text-uppercase">
              <a class="text-dark" href="{% url 'course-list' %}?q={{major.major}}">{{major.major}}</a>
            </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
...
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-nowrap">
      {% if is_paginated %}

        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == num %}
              <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
              <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
        {% endif %}

      {% endif %}
    </div>
...
```

At the moment, I can filter all courses by major, paginate all courses but only on the page that has all the courses. The current results are either this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/?q=Computer%20Science
```

or this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/?page=2
```

Now I'd like to have both filtering and pagination at the same time, how can i achieve this?
The desired result should look like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/?q=Computer%20Science&page=2
```

Thank you in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create templatetag:

```
@register.simple_tag()
def relative_url(value, field_name, urlencode=None):
    """
    TemplateTag for special django-filter url with pagination
    """
    url = '?{}={}'.format(field_name, value)
    if urlencode:
        querystring = urlencode.split('&')
        filtered_querystring = filter(lambda p: p.split('=')[0] != field_name, querystring)
        encoded_querystring = '&'.join(filtered_querystring)
        url = '{}&{}'.format(url, encoded_querystring)
    return url
```

and then use it in your paginate html:

```
{% load your_name_of_templatetag %}

{% for i in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if page_obj.number == i %}
        <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
            <a class="page-link" href="{% relative_url i 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ i }}</a>
        </li>
    {% elif i > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and i < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="{% relative_url i 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ i }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: can you show me how to implement this new href for the has previous and has next too :')